# Android Firefox not showing scrollbar in iframe

Tags: android, html, firefox, iframe

I was visiting this iframe example page in Firefox mobile for Android:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

There is no scrollbar showing as i scroll inside the iframe, it does on chrome mobile tho. Is it expected behavior? How do i make it appear for firefox.

Comment: Nothing to see here. This is pretty normal. If you WANT scrollbars to show regardless, then you'll need to make them yourself.

Comment: @aaronburrows then provide the reason why firefox would disable scrollbars for iframes in particular.

Comment: ...Because it's a mobile device. There's no mouse cursor, and scrolling is handled by direct touch interface.